# How to fix this error "getFirstName is not a function"

Tags: html, angular

I've created a function inside the **Student** class but when I called it in **student.component.html** it appears this error **getFirstName is not a function**.

### This is student.component.html

```html
<div *ngFor="let student of students">
    <p>{{student.getFirstName()}}</p>
</div>
```

### This is student.component.ts

```js
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Student } from 'src/app/models/Student';
import { StudentService } from 'src/app/services/student.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-student',
  templateUrl: './student.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./student.component.css'],
})
export class StudentComponent implements OnInit {
  students: Student[] = [];

  constructor(private studentService: StudentService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void { this.getAllStudents(); }

  public getAllStudents(): void {
    this.studentService.getAllStudents().subscribe(
      (response: Student[]) => {
        this.students = response;
        console.log(this.students);
      },
      (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        alert(error.message);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

### This is the Student class

```js
export class Student {

    private id: BigInt | undefined;
    private first_name: String;
    private last_name: String;
    private email: String;
    private phone: String;
    private image_url: String | undefined;
    private level: String;
    private cin: String;
    //private Subjects subjects;


    constructor(first_name: String, last_name: String, email: String, phone: String, image_url: String, level: String, cin: String) {
        this.first_name = first_name;
        this.last_name = last_name;
        this.email = email;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.image_url = image_url;
        this.level = level;
        this.cin = cin;
    }

    public getFirstName(): String { return this.first_name; }
}
```

### And this is the error

[image]

Comment: You are using Angular, and Typescript like a Java developer.

Answer (score 2):

response array not being instances of the Student class.

Try this,

```
public getAllStudents(): void {
  this.studentService.getAllStudents().subscribe(
    (response: any[]) => {
      this.students = response.map(student => new Student(
        student.first_name,
        student.last_name,
        student.email,
        student.phone,
        student.image_url,
        student.level,
        student.cin,
      ));
      console.log(this.students);
    },
    (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      alert(error.message);
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your help, this solves the problem.